# Isomorphism between field and polynomial ring over the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $\bar{k}$ be an algebraically closed field, $a,b \in \bar{k}$. I want to show that $(x-a,y-b) \subset \bar{k}[x,y]$ is maximal. How can I prove that $\bar{k}[x,y]/(x-a,y-b) \cong \bar{k}$ ?

Comment: A constant one, but we did not use anything about $a,b$. Can we get all elements in $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the field is algebraically closed is irrelevant.

The homomorphism $\varphi\colon k[x,y]\to k$ ($k$ any field) defined by $\varphi(x)=a$ and $\varphi(y)=b$ is surjective, so its kernel is maximal.

Clearly $x-a\in\ker\varphi$ and $y-b\in\ker\varphi$, so $(x-a,y-b)\subseteq\ker\varphi$. Now let's take $f(x,y)\in\ker\varphi$.

We can write $f(x,y)=(y-b)g(x,y)+h(x)$. We're just doing long division in $R[y]$, where $R=k[x]$ and long division is always possible when the divisor is monic.

Evaluating at $x=a$ and $y=b$ yields
$$
h(a)=0
$$
so that $h(x)$ is divisible by $x-a$. Hence $h(x)=(x-a)k(x)$ and therefore
$$
f(x,y)=(x-a)k(x)+(y-b)g(x,y)\in(x-a,y-b)
$$
This proves that $\ker\varphi\subseteq(x-a,y-b)$, so we are done.

---

#### Long division in polynomial rings.

*Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $g(x)$ be a monic polynomial in $R[x]$. For every $f(x)\in R[x]$ there exist unique polynomials $q(x),r(x)\in R[x]$ such that $\deg r(x)<\deg g(x)$ and $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$.*

(Convention: the degree of the zero polynomial is $-\infty$.)

Existence is by induction on $\deg f(x)$. The statement is obvious for $f(x)=0$, so we can assume $f(x)\ne0$. Suppose the statement holds for every polynomial of degree less than $\deg f(x)$.

If $\deg f(x)<\deg g(x)$ we have nothing to prove, so assume $\deg f(x)\ge \deg g(x)$. Write $f(x)=a^mx^m+f_1(x)$, where $m=\deg f(x)$ and $\deg f_1(x)<m$. Then $g(x)=x^n+g_1(x)$, with $\deg g=n\le m$ and $\deg g_1(x)<n$.

Consider $f_0(x)=f(x)-a_mx^{m-n}g(x)=a_mx^m+f_1(x)-a_mx^{m-n}x^n-a_mx^{m-n}g_1(x)$, which proves that $\deg f_0(x)<\deg f(x)$ and, by the induction hypothesis,
$$
f_0(x)=g(x)q_1(x)+r(x)
$$
with $\deg r<\deg g$. Then
$$
f(x)=g(x)(a_mx^{m-n}+q_1(x))+r(x)
$$
as we wanted to prove. Uniqueness is easy.

Comment: Can you explain how the long division of $f(x,y)$ is possible? Also we are assuming that $\phi(1)=1$, right?

Comment: @Ninja I added the standard proof. And yes, I assume that $\varphi(c)=c$ for every $c\in k$.

Comment: One last question:
How can we show that $( (\bar{k}[x,y])/ f(x,y) ) / (x-a) \cong \bar{k}[y] / (f(a,y))$ ?

Comment: @Ninja Where do you need that?

Comment: Well, it is at page 86 of Lorenzini's An Invitation to Arithmetic Geometry. The aim of the topic was to factorize ideal generated by $(x-a)$ in $C_f = \bar{k}[x,y]/(f)$

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:k[x,y]\rightarrow k$ by $f(x)=a, f(y)=b, f(1)=1$, it is not trivial (surjective«) and its kernel conatins the maximal ideal $(x-a,x-b)$ sot it is that ideal.

You can also remark that if $p:k[x,y]\rightarrow k[x,y]/(x-a,y-b)$ is the quotient map, for every $h\in k[x,y]$, $p(h)=p(h(a,b))$ so $h\in (x-a,x-b)$ i.e $h(a,b)=f(h)=0$ i.e $h\in ker(f)$.

Comment: How do we say that it is surjective?

Comment: because its $f(x+c-a)=c$.

Comment: I still can not understand why $g \in ker(f) \implies g \in (x-a,y-b)?$

Comment: The question is to prove that the ideal is maximal, so the ending of the first paragraph is incorrect.

Comment: @egreg, do you mean my last sentence? What is the field that is isomorphic to the quotient, then?